# How to show that every prime ideal is a maximal ideal if for all $a \in R$ there exists $b \in R$ such that $a^2b=a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Here is the full statement of the question (I thought it was a bit too long for the title).

> Given a commutative ring $R$ with $1 \neq 0$ such that for all $a \in R$ there exists $b \in R$ such that $a^2b=a$. Show that in $R$ every prime ideal is maximal.

I was trying to show that every ideal wich has a prime ideal as a strict subset is $R$. I was trying to do this by showing that $1$ would be an element of such an ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: Try showing that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Factoid: Rings like this are called [strongly regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_ring#Generalizations), and they are exactly the von Neumann regular rings without nonzero nilpotent elements.

Comment: @rschwieb What rings? As far as I can see the OP works within a VNR.

Comment: @YACP Rings where $\forall a \exists b(a^2b=a)$. It's strictly stronger than $\forall a\exists b(aba=a)$. There's no distinction in the commutative case, of course.

Comment: @rschwieb Then maybe you had to mention that the OP works with a VNR and there are non-commutative generalizations of this class of rings. Otherwise I find confusing your comment.

Comment: Dear @YACP : That's unfortunate. I'm sure if Leo feels the same way he'll contact me with questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the quotient $A=R/\mathfrak p$  of $R$ modulo a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$.
In $A$ we still have the property that for each $a\in A$ there exists $b$ with $a^2b=a$, i.e. $a(ab-1)=0$. Since $A$ has no zero-divisors, this implies $ab=1$ if $a\ne 0$. In other words, $A$ is a field and hence $\mathfrak p$ maximal.

---

Of course the argument can also be carried out directly in $R$, but the view via the quotients is where the proof "comes from": Let $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal containing $\mathfrak p$ and assume there exists $a\in\mathfrak m\setminus\mathfrak p$. Using $a^2b=a$ for some $b\in R$ we obtain $a(ab-1)=0\in\mathfrak p$, hence $ab-1\in \mathfrak p\subseteq\mathfrak m$. As $a\in\mathfrak m$, this implies $1\in\mathfrak m$, contradiction.

Comment: I still have some small questions:
Hagen, you say there are no zero-divisors in A. Is this a property of rings modulo a prime ideal?
YACP I don't get wy $ab -1$ should be an element of m.

Thanks for your help guys, really appreciate it!

Comment: $p$ is prime in $R$ iff $R/p$ is an integral domain.